# what is the corresponding lock method in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In Oracle, there are 2 procedures that used DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST and DBMS_LOCK.RELEASE

```
lock_status := DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST(
    lockhandle => get_handle(lock_name),
    lockmode => DBMS_LOCK.X_MODE, -- eXclusive
    timeout => DBMS_LOCK.MAXWAIT, -- wait forever
    release_on_commit => FALSE);

lock_status := DBMS_LOCK.RELEASE(
    lockhandle => get_handle(lock_name));
```

And the get_handle function as bellow:

```
create or replace FUNCTION                        get_handle (lock_name IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  lock_handle VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOCK.ALLOCATE_UNIQUE (
    lockname => lock_name,
    lockhandle => lock_handle,
    expiration_secs => 864000); -- 10 days
  RETURN lock_handle;
END get_handle;
```

I need to migrate DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST and DBMS_LOCK.RELEASE into PostgreSQL. I have researched Google, and look at 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/explicit-locking.html
and 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/view-pg-locks.html

And still trying to understand what is method I should to use for these locks. If you know about this, please help to advise.

Thanks,

Comment: I think the corresponding feature in Postgres are [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS)

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you reading the manual for an obsolete and unsupported version? Are you really using 9.1? Then you should plan an upgrade to the current version now.

Comment: Thanks for response. I just try to check some documents to know about lock behavior in PostgreSQL. And you are correct, I have updated script to use advisory_locks.